# How to avoid displaying the results of an API query when assigning a variable

Tags: ruby, google-api-ruby-client

I am using the `google-api-client` gem to interact with Google Calendar.

When saving a list of events like this:

```rb
@events = calendar.list_events(@tmpcalendar)
```

The output of `calendar.list_events(@tmpcalendar)` is *huge*. I just want to save the result to `@events` (don't need the huge content displayed).

I have tried: `$output.close`, redirecting to `/dev/null`, appending `;nil`; but the huge result is displayed anyway.

To replicate this (with a solution that works) you can

```rb
large_text = <<~EOS
  ...huge text here
  ...huge text here
  ...huge text here
  ...
  ...huge text here
EOS

eventos_good = large_text ; nil  # Assigns the content, does not display it
eventos_annoying = large_text    # Assigns the content, but displays the huge text
```

This works for that case, but does not work with the above scenario (API call).

Is it possible to avoid that huge output just for that variable assignment above?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you now talking about running your code in `irb`, or do you mean directly in a Ruby script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [to the docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/docs/logging.md), the Google API gem has debug logging enabled by default. To decrease the output, set the logging lever to something higher:

```
Google::Apis.logger.level = Logger::FATAL 
# INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL each decrease the output. 
# FATAL is the most restrictive.
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From your code, it looks like you're using the Google API Client gem? Which version?

If you're not using this gem in a Rails application, then it will default all logging to `$stdout`: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/1135e74c4896d4ec8aa02c14e3532d9a14514815/lib/google/apis.rb#L34-L40

If you want to completely silence the logging, then override the logger:

```rb
require 'logger'

Google::Apis.logger = Logger.new(nil)
```